# I am following the instructions for circular references on the RequireJS site, but it doesn't work

Tags: requirejs, circular-dependency

I have a simple case that I believe follows the instructions in the RequestJS doc:  http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#circular  However, it doesn't seem to work.  I have put my files below, and a zip file in dropbox:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/5h7hlj281cddh5t/program_version_2.zip?dl=0  Can someone tell me what is going on?

```
index.html:
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <script data-main="js/app" src="js/require.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
Loaded.
</body>
</html>

app.js:
requirejs.config({
    paths: {
        'module1': 'module1',
        'module2': 'module2'
    }
});

requirejs(['main'], function(main) {
    main.start();
});


main.js:
define(['module1'], function (module1) {

    var start = function() {

        console.log('In main.js.  Before initializeValues.');

        module1.doOperation();

    }

    return {
        start: start
    };
});


module1.js:
define(['require', 'module2'],
function (require, module2) {

    var doOperation = function() {
        console.log('Start of doOperation function');

        require('module2').someFunc();
    };

    var anotherFunc = function() {
        console.log('In anotherFunc.');
    };

    return {
        doOperation: doOperation,
        anotherFunc: anotherFunc
    };

});


module2.js:
require(['require', 'module1'], function(require, module1) {

    var someFunc = function() {
        console.log('In someFunc.');
        require('module1').anotherFunc();
    };

    return {
        someFunc: someFunc
    };
});


require.js:
/** vim: et:ts=4:sw=4:sts=4
 * @license RequireJS 2.0.4 Copyright (c) 2010-2012, The Dojo Foundation All Rights Reserved.
 * Available via the MIT or new BSD license.
 * see: http://github.com/jrburke/requirejs for details
 */
/*jslint regexp: true, nomen: true */
/*global window, navigator, document, importScripts, jQuery, setTimeout, opera */

var requirejs, require, define;
(function (global) {
    'use strict';

    var version = '2.0.4',
        commentRegExp = /(\/\*([\s\S]*?)\*\/|([^:]|^)\/\/(.*)$)/mg,
        cjsRequireRegExp = /[^.]\s*require\s*\(\s*["']([^'"\s]+)["']\s*\)/g,
        jsSuffixRegExp = /\.js$/,
            :          :
```

I get the message in the console:  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'someFunc' of undefined . . . . module1.js:7

It's difficult to move forward when I don't feel I understand what RequireJS is doing.  Can someone shed light?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `module2.js` you have:

```
require(['require', 'module1'], function(require, module1) {
```

You want to use:

```
define(['require', 'module1'], function(require, module1) {
```

You need to use `define` to define the module.

Comment: Yup, that solves the problem.  Thanks!  Now I'll go back to the original problem, that I simplified down to this, and see whether I can make it work.  I tried to vote your answer up, but it said I had too poor of a reputation.  !